# why don't operate "make" instruction to kernel-compile?

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-16.04, vmware-workstation

i want to kernel-compile at linux-5.2.9, but make not operate after `make clean`.
how should i do?

i show tryed list

tar xfJ linux-5.2.9

cd linux-5.2.9

pwd

ls

apt-get -y install qt5-default libssl-dev

make mrproper - kernel init

make xconfig ( File systems ) -> (DOS/FAT/NT Filesystem ) -> (NTFS filesystem support ) low-level check all

make clean

make < - **from error**

make modules_install

make install

[image]

Comment: The message says `Please update your compiler.`

Comment: i tryed after that.